# Continuous Extension of $f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto \frac{{x_1 \sin(x_2) + x_2 \sin(x_1)}}{{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, continuity

Investigate at which points on $\partial D$ the function can be continuously extended, and in this case, provide the continuous extension.

$f : D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $x \mapsto \frac{{x_1 \sin(x_2) + x_2 \sin(x_1)}}{{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2}}}$

I have tried to disprove that $f(x_1, x_2)$ has a continuous extension at $(0,0)$. Specifically, I used straight lines, but the limit always seems to approach zero. Therefore, I plotted the graph, and indeed, it seems like a continuous extension is possible. My question is as follows: If that is the case, how do I show it? It seems impossible to prove in every possible direction. Can I maybe use sequences, or what should I do in this situation? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In polar coordinates we have $f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)=\cos \theta \sin (r sin \theta)+\sin \theta \sin (r cos \theta)$, so $|f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)| \le |\sin (r sin \theta)|+|\sin (r cos \theta)|$.

So $f(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) \to 0$ as $(r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) \to (0,0)$.